Deleted my EFI/MS & MSR partitions by error, how to rebuild it?
I accidentally deleted every single partition of my computer except the one that Windows is installed on it. I thought it was a good idea. But it was not.
I have no more MSR or EFI partition, so when I boot it gives an error. I have two disks, one remained untouched and the other disk has Windows on it and had MSR and EFI partitions.
Is there is a way to rebuild those ? There's no problem if it takes time or something; it's not my main computer. I just don't wanna lose the data that are on all the
partitions. (since I only deleted partitions where I thought there nothing)
WHAT I'VE TRIED:

Boot into Windows (Tiny10, actually) installation media
Get a CMD working by Shift+F10
Run some bootrec commands I got from the web



Boot into Linux (MX Linux exactly) live media
Run GParted
Recreate a partition in FAT32/FAT16 (I tried both) with flags ESD



Install a new Linux system on a second partition (didn't worked as the EFI partition is gone)

Thanks in advance.
Similar question (if not the same): windows efi and system reserved partition mistakenly deleted (posting this to hope there's a solution with no reset)
Also, I don't much care if I can no longer use Windows

You deleted the partition (EFI) with the boot configuration data; the commands you ran require that data to exist so it can be detected. Had you not created new partitions, you might have been able to detect the deleted partitions.  Your actions have made that now impossible. If you don't care about the Windows partition, you should just reinstall Windows. Why are you recovering two partitions that would only be required if you were trying to boot into Windows?

With UEFI, the EFI boot files cannot be rebuilt directly via BootRec /FixBoot unless the EFI partition is mounted and entered first (see Steps 2 & 5), otherwise an Access Denied error will occur; instead, once the EFI partition is mounted at Y: via DiskPart: BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Y: /f UEFI (the OS partition is normally not C: in WinPE/WinRE). Once done, resolve remaining boot issues via: BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD and reboot, even if no Windows installations are found.

If you want to restore your data, then start by trying to restore the data partitions, not by taking a detour somewhere else. Recovering the EFI partitions will not help you with recovering data partitions – more likely it will only be harmful, in case the process ends up creating a new EFI partition right on top of where data was.
Deleted partitions can be re-created as long as the new partition has exactly the same start sector (and as long as the tool doesn't "helpfully" erase contents). The testdisk Linux tool can be used to scan for deleted partitions.

To make the disk bootable, you'll first need to manually create and format the EFI partition using GParted or diskpart; then it can be filled in with files using bcdboot (from the Shift-F10 console), which will copy the original bootloader files from \Windows\Boot and will generate a new BCD config. See official Microsoft docs.
The MSR partition is meaningless; you can also create it using diskpart but it only exists to reserve space and not to store anything. [Not to be confused with the "System Reserved" partition of similar name that Windows uses on BIOS disks!]


C:\> diskpart
DISKPART> sel disk ...


Create the EFI partition (efi makes DISKPART automatically set the correct GPT type guid):
create partition efi size=100
format quick fs=fat32 label="System"
assign letter="S"


Create the MSR partition if you want:
create partition msr size=16


Assuming the system disk is accessible at C:\Windows:
bcdboot c:\windows /s S: /f UEFI /v

/s S: tells it to specifically use the recently created partition instead of guessing; and since I don't trust "Tiny10" to properly boot in UEFI mode, /f UEFI tells bcdboot to specifically copy the EFI files even if that's not what the installer is booted through.


The procedure is almost the same for BIOS (legacy) boot as well – except instead of "EFI System" FAT32 partition you have a "Microsoft System" NTFS partition, and the DISKPART commands are slightly different, but it is still populated using the same bcdboot (/f BIOS) in the end. See Microsoft docs.

Create the system partition:

create partition primary size=100
format quick fs=ntfs label="System"
assign letter="S"
active


There is no MSR partition on BIOS/MBR disks.

Use bcdboot with /f BIOS.


(There would be an additional "boot sector" step when starting from a clean disk, but the MBR boot sector was not deleted – it exists outside of any partition – so you probably don't need to reinstall it.)

TestDisk might be able to detect the deleted partitions. However, you have created partitions, so the chances of success is greatly diminished. I give up on trying to recover the two partitions and just recreate them. As for your data partition, that’s something else entirely, every single action you take on the action disk instead of a clone will decrease the chances of data recovery from a data partition

Thanks for your reply, but while my computer is UEFI, I always kept it in Legacy mode, and my disks aren't GPT (how did I do that...) - so I don't really know what kind of partition did I deleted, but my computer surely won't boot. I think I'll have to reinstall Windows, but backing up my data is a bit of a problem: the only disk I might store my data on is locked by Windows due to it's fast startup feature - I might recreate a question to ask how to get write access on that locked disk. Or create a "temporary partition" to copy my Windows data on it using a Live Linux distro. - Thanks anyways

Why did you specifically ask how to create the EFI partition then, if you're now telling me that you don't want it?

It's because I didn't knew it wasn't a GPT disk, but thought it as the Windows Installer never booted in Legacy mode (and I temporarily enabled UEFI mode) but it still installed in Legacy mode... Yeah, I don't know what I've done.

Well, in that case, the procedure for legacy boot on MBR disks is nearly the same – you still create the "Microsoft System" partition, format it as NTFS (instead of FAT), and fill it using the same bcdboot.

(Although you can use this opportunity to convert the disk to GPT... but after you've recovered data, not before.)

@HGStyle - If Windows was installed in legacy mode then it's impossible to have deleted the EFI partition. What you have asked and are now telling us are the facts cannot coexist in reality. If Windows was installed in Legacy Mode it's impossible for the disk to have been GPT.  You need to fix the inconsistences in your question.

@HGStyle To piggy-back on Ramhound's comment, Windows should never be installed with CSM Mode enabled. The sole purpose of CSM Mode was to enable distros lacking EFI boot the ability to boot circa <2017 (Windows has supported EFI boot since Win 7). The only purpose for CSM Mode after 2017 is to enter legacy OPROMs, and it should be re-disabled after exiting the OPROM. CSM Mode results in severe performance degradation since it forces UEFI [64bit] to emulate BIOS [16bit] in a 32bit environment, with boot times increasing by 400%+


Linux tools are not needed to fix Windows and are inefficient to use to do so: WinPE/WinRE: Resolve boot issues via BootRec/BcdBoot, partition issues via DiskPart/mbr2gpt 

Per OP's comment under grawity_u1686's answer, info not included within OP's question:

...[W]hile my computer is UEFI, I always kept it in Legacy mode, and my disks aren't GPT... so I don't really know what kind of partition did I deleted, but my computer... won't boot.



To Resolve:

Enter the UEFI Firmware Settings:

Disable: CSM Mode

CSM Mode's sole purpose was to enable distros lacking EFI boot the ability to boot circa <2017 (Windows ≥7 supports EFI boot)
CSM Mode results in performance degradation, forcing UEFI [64bit] to emulate BIOS [16bit] in a 32bit environment


Enable: Secure Boot 


Boot a Windows Install USB → Open a terminal: Shift+F10 

Convert OS drive to GPT via Mbr2Gpt:
::# Ascertain OS drive #:
    DiskPart

    ::# List drives:
        Lis Dis
        Exit

::# Convert OS drive from MBR to GPT:
    Mbr2Gpt /Convert /Disk:#


Verify Mbr2Gpt created the requisite Boot and MSR partitions:
DiskPart

::# List drives (ensure OS drive has GPT asterisk next to it):
    Lis Dis

::# Select OS drive number:
    Sel Dis #

::# List partitions
    Lis Par


If drive has EFI and MSR partitions: Skip to Step 5 


Create Boot and MSR partitions at the front of the drive:
::# If Dual-Booting:
    ::# Windows requires a 100MB EFI partition, whereas distros 
    ::# require different sizes, with max being ~750MB; sum both
    ::# to avoid issues

Cre Par EFI Size=100
Format Quick Fs=FAT32 Label="EFI"
Assign Letter=Y
Cre Par Msr Size=16



Re-create WinRE partition at the end of the drive if it was deleted:
::# Verify if WinRE partition still exists:
    Lis Par

    ::# WinRE partition can't be deleted without an override due to
    ::# its attribute flag, so it could still exist

::# If it doesn't, select last partition on the drive:
    Sel Par #

::# Recreate WinRE partition:
    Shrink Desired=1024 Minimum=1024
    Cre Par Pri Id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
    Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label="WinRE"
    Gpt Attributes=0x8000000000000001

::# Get OS partition mount point:
    Lis Vol
    Exit



Rebuild boot files and Resolve boot issues:

If Step 4 was skipped, mount EFI partition at Y: first:
DiskPart

::# List volumes:
    Lis Vol

::# Select and mount the EFI partition:
    Sel Vol #
    Assign Letter=Y
    Exit



::# EFI boot files cannot be rebuilt directly via BootRec /FixBoot
::# unless the EFI partition is mounted and "EFI\Microsoft\Boot" is
::# entered first, otherwise an Access Denied error will occur

::# C: is the OS partition from Step 5:
    BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Y: /f UEFI

::# Resolve any other boot issues:
    BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD

::# Remove EFI mountpoint:
    DiskPart

      Sel Vol Y
      Remove
      Exit





Reboot to Windows → Open an Admin terminal:  +R → Open: powershell → Ctrl+Shift+OK 

Enable WinRE:
# Ensure WinRE is disabled:
  ReAgentC /Disable

# Verify if Winre.wim exists:
  ls "C:\Windows\System32\Recovery" | FindStr /I "Winre.wim" ; ls "C:\Windows\System32\Recovery" -Hidden | FindStr /I "Winre.wim"

If Winre.wim:

Exists:
# Enable and verify:
  ReAgentC /Enable ; ReAgentC /Info


Doesn't Exist:  Extract it from a mounted Windows install ISO's install.<esd|wim>

ESD:  ESDs can't be mounted, so use 7zip to extract instead
# Get list of images [indexes] within the ESD:
  Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"E:\sources\install.esd"

# Replace '<#>' with the Windows version index # (usually index 1: Home | 6: Pro):
  & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e '-i!<#>\Windows\System32\Recovery\Winre.wim' 'E:\sources\install.esd' -o'C:\Windows\System32\Recovery'

# Enable WinRE and verify:
  ReAgentC /Enable ; ReAgentC /Info


WIM:  Built-in way to do so, although same 7zip command can be used
# Get list of images [indexes] within the WIM:
  Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"E:\sources\install.wim"

# Mount WIM (usually index 1: Home | 6: Pro):
  MkDir "C:\Mount" ; Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"E:\sources\install.wim" /Index:1 /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /ReadOnly

# Copy over Winre.wim:
  Xcopy "C:\Mount\Windows\System32\Recovery\Winre.wim" "$env:WinDir\System32\Recovery\Winre.wim"

# Unmount image, discard changes:
  Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /Discard

# Cleanup:
  RmDir -Recurse "C:\Mount"

# Enable WinRE and verify:
  ReAgentC /Enable ; ReAgentC /Info








Serial Down Voter: Care to explain what precisely is wrong with the steps in this answer? (There are none, as I've tested and verified each one prior to posting)

Linux tools are not needed to fix Windows and are inefficient to do so Linux vs. Windows discussion most likely. :-)

@ThorstenSchöning That's a factual statement, not an opinion: From its native boot environments WinPE/WinRE, not Linux, boot issues are resolved via BootRec and BcdBoot, with partition issues resolved via DiskPart and mbr2gpt.

While "Linux tools are not needed" is factual, the note about efficiency seems less so. If more care was taken initially to not damage the partition contents it would've been easier to restore the partition with testdisk.

@JensV How is needing a secondary, non-supported boot environment more efficient than the actual incl. and supported environment? What Linux utilities are used to build the BCD Store? Why would a Linux LiveUSB be used when BootRec is required and is incl. within WinPE/WinRE? Where is the evidence to support using Linux boot environments and Linux utilities are more efficient than WinPE/WinRE? Ever timed it? How is one to know what Linux utilities to use and where is that even recommended? Ever come across advice telling a Linux user to user Wine or Windows to resolve a Linux boot issue?

Basic common sense seems to have been left at the door if a simple factual statement is being interpreted as Linux vs Windows, which has nothing to do with this Q/A. Before commenting with something similar, please incl. within the comment the equivalent utilities in Linux to replace BootRec, BcdBoot, DiskPart, and Mbr2Gpt, what distros have all of them included within their LiveUSB ISO by default (my hunch is none, since this entire concept is absurdity), and how many tens of pages need to be sifted through on a search engine to find these utilities. Come on now folks...

@JW0914 You were asking where the down-vote comes from, my comment was an educated guess about the reason. I don't think there's anything wrong with your answer, but that quoted statement might simply trigger some people.

I don't understand where this even comes from. Nobody was even suggesting to use Linux tools as a replacement for bootrec et al [it was suggested for the data partitions that OP mentioned having deleted], so even the originai header in bold was unprompted – and now you've got half a screenful worth of arguing against it on top of that. (More so when you're now asking for "where's the evidence" when you used to completely dismiss any evidence anyway, back when we were discussing dism a few months ago.) I think you need to chill.

@ThorstenSchöning I asked the serial down voter, not the SU community at whole. Unless you're the downvoter, please don't intuit their motives.

@grawity_u1686 The statement was for the OP, not anyone's answers, jumping around between Linux and Windows to resolve a Windows issue. Please see comment from Jens - implication was it's more efficient to use Linux to resolve issues those Windows utilities were specifically made for. OP never stated they deleted data partitions containing data, only the EFI, MSR, and partitions they believed were empty (no reason to recover partitions that are empty). It's absurd for anyone to even suggest Linux is more efficient to resolve Windows boot issues because the facts have never supported that
